# Struct constructor breakpoints not getting hit in external code

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, breakpoints

I've noticed that if I have the following code and call `System.Array`'s `GetEnumerator` method:

```
    var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var arrayEnumerator = array.GetEnumerator();
    arrayEnumerator.MoveNext();
```

The same thing happens with `List`'s enumerator, it does not stop inside `List.Enumerator` ctor:

```
    var list = new List<int>();
    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
```

[image: jj]

it does not stop at the breakpoint that I put in the `ArrayEnumerator`'s constructor:

[image]

Doesn't really matter what IDE I use - Rider and the latest Visual Studio 2022 (with just my code disabled of course) behave the same way (checked both .NET 6 and 7 runtime).

I was thinking that maybe it is caused by constructor inlining, but inspecting IL shows it's not really the case.

[image]

If I put a breakpoint in `ArrayEnumerator` methods like `MoveNext`, they work just fine.

[image]

**Interestingly though**, when I create a `Stack`, it works as expected and the breakpoint inside `Stack.Enumerator` gets hit:

```
    var stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: `MoveNext` wasn't shown in your code, how does the actual code look like? If you set a breakpoint on the second line then step in, what will happen?

Comment: @shingo updated

Comment: You followed the recommendations here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/debug-aspnetcore-source?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Nikolay yes, and I've even tried other combinations, no luck.

Comment: You haven't replied my second question, can you step into `array.GetEnumerator` till the constructor?

Comment: @shingo Yes I can step into array.GetEnumerator which calls new new ArrayEnumerator(this), and then when I step into it just jumps back to my program's Main method completely ignoring the new ArrayEnumerator(this) call. I've just added one observation that it actually works for Stack<T>, but not for List/Array...

Comment: @user5539357 Once again, go over all the recommendations there very carefully. I just copied your code and in debugging I managed to stop in the ArrayEnumerator constructor

Comment: Are you sure you've set COMPlus_ReadyToRun to 0?

Comment: @user5539357 The COMPlus_ReadyToRun environment variable must be set to 0.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you. Never used it to be honest, for some reason I thought it only applied to ASP.NET apps. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why the author's constructor was not available for debugging was that one of the restrictions for executing the `Suppress JIT optimization` option was triggered.

The code to be debugged is placed in an assembly that is built with precompiled native code. To exclude the launch of such code you should specify the `COMPlus_ReadyToRun=0` environment variable.

Here is a detailed explanation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/jit-optimization-and-debugging